# How  Binomial and Normal distributions approximate Poisson distribution respectively?

Tags: probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution):

1. In some cases, the cdf of the Poisson distribution is the limit of
   the cdf of the binomial distribution：

   > The Poisson distribution can be derived as a limiting case to the
   >   binomial distribution $\text{bin}(n,p)$ as the number $n$ of trials
   >   goes to infinity and the expected number $np$ of successes remains
   >   fixed — see law of rare events below. Therefore it can be used as an
   >   approximation of the binomial distribution if $n$ is sufficiently
   >   large and $p$ is sufficiently small.
2. In some cases, the cdf of the Poisson distribution is the limit of
   the cdf of the normal distribution:

   > For sufficiently large values of $λ$, (say $λ>1000$), the normal
   >   distribution with mean $λ$ and variance $λ$ (standard deviation
   >   $\sqrt{\lambda}$), is an excellent approximation to the Poisson
   >   distribution. If $λ$ is greater than about $10$, then the normal
   >   distribution is a good approximation if an appropriate continuity
   >   correction is performed, i.e., $P(X ≤ x)$, where (lower-case) $x$ is a
   >   non-negative integer, is replaced by $P(X ≤ x + 0.5)$. $$
   >              F_\mathrm{Poisson}(x;\lambda) \approx F_\mathrm{normal}(x;\mu=\lambda,\sigma^2=\lambda)\, $$

I wonder in what best senses these functional approximations are? Pointwise, uniformly, $L_2$, ...?
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In some cases, the cdf of the Poisson distribution is the limit of the cdf of the normal distribution:"

That is false.  The limit of Poisson distributions is a normal distribution; the limit of normal distributions is not a Poisson distribution.

"Best senses" is a term I've never come across and I don't know what you mean by it.

Suppose $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$.  Then the cdf of $(X-\lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ converges pointwise to the cdf of the standard normal distribution as $\lambda\to\infty$.

Now suppose $X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,\lambda/n)$.  Then the cdf of $X$ converges pointwise to the cdf of the Poisson distribution with expectation $\lambda$ as $n\to\infty$.

Generally "convergence in distribution" means a sequence of cdf's converges to a cdf pointwise *except* that it need not converge at points where the limiting cdf is not continuous.  The reason for the exception is things like this: Concentrate probability $1$ at $1/n$.  Then the value of the cdf at $0$ is $0$.  But the limiting cdf has value $1$ at $0$; that's where it concentrates all the probability.

But don't write about normal distributions approaching a Poisson distribution.  It's the other way around.

Comment: Thanks! But that is what I understood from the Wikipedia article, unless it is wrong.

Comment: @Tim, WP is right on this, you might wish to read the paragraph again.

Comment: Wikipedia says the normal distribution approximates the Poisson distribution under certain circumstances.  But that doesn't mean the normal is approaching the Poisson.  It's the Poisson that's approaching the normal.

Comment: @Didier and Michael: Thanks! According to the Wiki article, (1) in the binomial distribution part, the convergence is when $n \rightarrow \infty$ with $np$ fixed, not $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$. Note $\lambda = np$. (2) in the normal distribution part, the convergence is $\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}    \text{discrepancy}( F_\mathrm{Poisson}(x;\lambda), F_\mathrm{normal}(x;\mu=\lambda,\sigma^2=\lambda)) = 0$, i.e. the two cdfs are approaching each other under some measure of discrepancy, instead of one approaching the other.

Comment: （3）Michael, in your reply, when you mentioned that the poisson distributions approach the standard normal distribution, is it the same as the Central Limit Theorem, or are there some differences?

Comment: If $\lambda$ takes only integer values while approacing $\infty$, then the result follows from the central limit theorem together with the fact that the sum of $\lambda$ independent random variables with expectation $1$ is a Poisson random variable with expectation $\lambda$.  Allowing $\lambda$ to take real values complicates the argument a bit, but that's not hard to overcome.

Comment: Michael, Thanks for answering my question (3). I wonder why "the sum of λ independent random variables with expectation 1 is a Poisson random variable with expectation λ"? Also do you have some idea as to questions (1) and (2) in my previous comment?

Comment: @Tim, I see no question in your (1) and (2).

Comment: @Didier: Refering to Michael's reply and my previous comment: for my (1), I would like to know if $n \rightarrow \infty$ with $np$ fixed is correct, or $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ in Michael's reply is correct; for my (2), I would like to know if my understanding of the two kinds of distributions approaching each other is correct, or one distribution approaching another in Michael's reply is correct. If I am correct, in what way do the two approach each other? (Let me know if I am still not clear. Thanks!)

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the explanations, I was too hasty in my first reading. In your (1), $\lambda\to\infty$ is a typo and should be replaced by $n\to\infty$ and $p\to0$ in a way such that $np\to\lambda$ with $\lambda$ positive and finite. In your (2), the mathematical result is that any $X_\lambda$ Poisson$(\lambda)$ are such that $(X_\lambda-\lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ converges in distribution to a standard Gaussian $Z$. Since $Z_\lambda=\sqrt{\lambda}Z+\lambda$ is a Gaussian with mean $\lambda$ and variance $\lambda$, one could be tempted to write .../...

Comment: .../... that $X_\lambda$ and $Z_\lambda$ have similar distributions. This needs some care since, for example, $X_\lambda$ is an integer with probability one and $Z_\lambda$ is an integer with probability zero. What you have, though, are bounds on the total variation distance between Poisson and normal random variables, often referred to by the generic name of *Stein's method*.

Comment: @Didier: Thanks! Nice to learn from you.

Comment: Michael, I wonder why "the sum of λ independent random variables with expectation 1 is a Poisson random variable with expectation λ"?

Comment: @Tim: Generally, the sum of two independent Poisson-distributed random variables is also a Poisson-distributed random variable. And once it works for two of them, it works for any finite number of them, as can be shown by mathematical induction. If $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\mu)$, then by the usual additivity of expectations, the expected value of $X+Y$ must be $\lambda+\mu$ (whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not), so _if_ $X+Y$ is Poisson-distributed, it must be that $X+Y\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda+\mu)$.  So the question is:

Comment: ...why must we have $X+Y\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda+\mu)$, if the assumptions above hold? I'll post a separate answer treating that question.

Comment: Michael, thanks! I thought you were saying $X$ and $Y$ have arbitrary distributions as long as they are independent with expectation 1. Now I don't think this way.

Comment: I would have thought that the "Now suppose ..." paragraph should end "... as $n \to \infty$" rather than "... as $\lambda \to \infty$"

Comment: @Henry : Correct.  I've fixed it.  Clearly $\lambda$ cannot be what's approaching $\infty$ if $\lambda$ is part of the value of the limit.

Comment: Intuitive and graphical approaches [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170045/approximation-of-operatornamepoisson-lambda-by-binomial/4170078#4170078).

Answer (score 3):

In comments above, Tim asked why it must be that if $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\mu)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then we must have $X+Y\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda+\mu)$.

Here's one way to show that.
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X+Y= w) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr\Big( (X=0\ \& \ Y=w)\text{ or }(X=1\ \&\ Y=w-1) \\
& {}\qquad\qquad\text{ or } (X=2\ \&\ Y=w-2)\text{ or } \ldots \text{ or }(X=0\ \&\ Y=w)\Big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{u=0}^w \Pr(X=u)\Pr(Y=w-u)\qquad(\text{independence was used here}) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{u=0}^w \frac{\lambda^u e^{-\lambda}}{u!} \cdot \frac{\mu^{w-u} e^{-\mu}}{(w-u)!} \\[8pt]
= {} & e^{-(\lambda+\mu)} \sum_{u=0}^w \frac{1}{u!(w-u)!} \mu^u\lambda^{w-u} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{w!} \sum_{u=0}^w \frac{w!}{u!(w-u)!} \mu^u\lambda^{w-u} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{w!} (\lambda+\mu)^w
\end{align}
and that is what was to be shown.